# Simple Captcha in PHP with rand()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a simple captcha in PHP, but it does not work. The query is not currently executing. This is my current code:

```
<?php
   $Random = rand(1, 100);
   $Random2 = rand(1,100);
   echo "Result: ".$Random." + ".$Random2." ?";
?>
<input type="text" name="r_input"/><br />

$Cap = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['r_input']);
$Result = $Random+$Random2;

if(isset($_POST['myButton']) and trim($Var) and trim($Var2) and trim($Var3) and $Cap==$Result){
   //My Query
}
```

Comment: This is not a captcha. A captcha is able to tell users and bots apart, which your script is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use rand() to generate 2 values, and show those 2 values, and give the form for the user to enter the answer, ...

... the user enters the answer and submits back to the server ...

... the server gets the answer, and then GENERATES 2 NEW VALUES, that don't correspond to the answer given by the user.

Try using session variables to store the generated values in, and match against when the user submits the form!

```
<?php
session_start();
$captcha_id = 'captcha_' . rand();
$_SESSION['$captcha_id']['val1'] = rand(1,1000);
$_SESSION['$captcha_id']['val2'] = rand(1,1000);
echo "
    <form action='' method='post'>
        <p>Result: {$_SESSION['$captcha_id']['val1']} + {$_SESSION['$captcha_id']['val2']} = </p>
        <input type='hidden' name='captcha_id' value='{$captcha_id}' />
        <input type='text' name='captcha_answer' />
        <p>?</p>
    </form>
";

if (
    isset($_POST['captcha_id'])
    && isset($_SESSION[$_POST['captcha_id']])
    && isset($_POST['captcha_answer'])
    && $_SESSION[$_POST['captcha_id']]['val1'] + $_SESSION[$_POST['captcha_id']]['val2'] == intval($_POST['captcha_answer'])
) {
    unset($_SESSION[$_POST['captcha_id']]); // don't let this answer be reused anymore.
    // do allowed stuff
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `$Random` and `$Random2` have a different value each time.

When you show the form for the first time, they may have the values `$Random = 12` and `$Random2 = 26`. The User sees those, adds them up correctly and types in `38` (which is the correct answer for those two values). The answer is sent to the script again, the values of `$Random` and `$Random2` are generated again (this time as `$Random = 23` and `$Random2 = 30` which equals 53) and the answer the user has sent is not correct any more.

So you would need to store those values in hidden fields and add these up, instead of the generated ones, like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="rand_1" value="<?php echo $Random; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="rand_2" value="<?php echo $Random2; ?>">

<?php
    if ($_POST['rand_1'] + $_POST['rand_2'] == $_POST['r_input']) {
    // Query etc.
```

**EDIT:** [As suggested by @nl-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20332759/simple-captcha-in-php-with-rand#20332907) you should use the Session variables instead of hidden fields to prevent abuse of the captcha:

```
<?php
    $Random = $_SESSION['rand_1'] = rand(1, 100);
    $Random2 = $_SESSION['rand_2'] = rand(1,100);
    echo "Result: ".$Random." + ".$Random2." ?";
?>
```

And check those values against the given result afterwards:

```
<?php
    $Cap = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['r_input']);
    $Result = $_SESSION['rand_1'] + $_SESSION['rand_2'];

    if ($Result == $Cap) {
    // ...
```

Comment: There is another way to do this without storing anything in the database?

Comment: You're not storing anything in the database with this simple script, you're just sending original the numbers along with the answer the user gave.

Comment: Try to just add those two hidden fields inside your `<form>` tag and replace the definition of `$Result` with `$Result = $_POST['rand_1'] + $_POST['rand_2'];`. Also add the missing `<?php` above `$Cap = ...`

Comment: Sorry!I had one thing I wrong in my complete script. It works perfectly. Thank you very much and sorry again

Comment: This is a very useless CAPTCHA. Because one could very easily always give along the same hidden values every time, which would always have the same answer! You need to store in the session vars or database. See my answer for session vars example...

Comment: @nl-x You're right. Although storing those values in the database might be a bit of an overkill, storing them in the session is generally better than sending them along. I myself would have used a reCAPTCHA or similar. I'll edit my answer to add your approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

You never re-enter PHP mode after you output your form field:

```
<input type="text" name="r_input"/><br />

<?php   // <----this is missing

$Cap = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['r_input']);
```

Comment: You're right but in the complete script there is so the problem it isn't this

Answer (score -1):

Pardon me, but you are not making a real captcha. The purpose of the captcha is to distinguish the human from the bots. I would highly suggest you to pick a image database, and randomize a function to call a image. Internally, i would check if the text/description of the image matches with what the user typed.

The only thing you will `rand()` is what image to load from your image database.

That's a not-healthy way to do it, and there are plenty of better ways to do this. But it's more closer to a captcha than just your current code.
There is also a lot of libraries and engines that can do the job for you.

I'm not a pro at PHP, or even programming at all, but i think you're going to the wrong side - your code won't block any... malicious actions at all, or whatever kind of action that you will try to prevent with the captcha.

Search google for the libraries. [PhpCaptcha is one of them.](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/) And [here](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/documentation/quickstart-guide/) is a very simple quickstart guide for phpcaptcha.

Here's a code example, extracted from PHPCaptch that I linked above.

At the desired position in your form, add the following code to display the CAPTCHA image:

```
<img id="captcha" src="/securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
```

Next, add the following HTML code to create a text input box:

```
<input type="text" name="captcha_code" size="10" maxlength="6" />
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = '/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false">[ Different Image ]</a>
```

On the very first line of the form processor, add the following code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

The following php code should be integrated into the script that processes your form and should be placed where error checking is done. It is recommended to place it after any error checking and only attempt to validate the captha code if no other form errors occured. **It should also be within**  tags.

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/securimage/securimage.php';
$securimage = new Securimage();
```

This includes the file that contains the Securimage source code and creates a new Securimage object that is responsible for creating, managing and validating captcha codes.

Next we will check to see if the code typed by the user was entered correctly.

```
if ($securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']) == false) {
  // the code was incorrect
  // you should handle the error so that the form processor doesn't continue
  // or you can use the following code if there is no validation or you do not know how
  echo "The security code entered was incorrect.<br /><br />";
  echo "Please go <a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>back</a> and try again.";
  exit;
}
```

Following the directions above should get Securimage working with minimal effort.
This code is included [here](https://www.phpcaptcha.org/documentation/quickstart-guide/) as well.

Good luck!